# SAPUI5 ObjectListItem icon not aligned

Tags: sapui5

I'm using an ObjectListItem with an icon in my SAPUI5 but the icon isn't always aligned to the text.

I have:

```
<List>
<ObjectListItem title="title" type="Active" number="{/data/value}"
icon="{= ${/data/value === '1' ? 'sap-icon://accept' : 'sap-icon://decline'}">
</ObjectListItem>
</List>
```

and styles:

```
.sapMObjLIconDiv {
    float: right;
    height: 0;}

.sapMObjLIcon.sapUiIcon {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
    margin: 0 auto;}
```

and value has different lengths and sometimes the icon appears over the text:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your custom CSS is the reason for the overlapping. You could add a margin to the the text so that it does not overlap the icon.

```
.sapMObjLNumberDiv{
    margin-right:60px;
}
```

Also I would recommend that you add a custom CSS class to the List and apply all your styling relative to that class. This will prevent any issues with other controls where similar standard classes are used.

Comment: Hi, but adding the margin will move everything. The thing is that as it is a data binded field, it has different lengths and I always need the icon before the text. Adding the margin will work for the second row ( of the image ) and for the first row, the icon will be too far the text.